# Upgrade Win 7 to Win 8 and remove Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-8, ubuntu-10.04

I have in my computer an installation of ubuntu (11.04) and Windows (7)

I want to remove the ubuntu installation and upgrade the windows to windows 8 **without** formatting my machine.

All the installations are located at `C:`

How can i do it? **without formatting**

**Edit**

I'm not using wubi

Comment: By that I understand you installed Ubuntu with Wubi? I.e. it resides within `C` drive instead on its own partition(s) right?

Comment: Yeah... Windows André ubuntu are In c:

Comment: Not using Wubi, yet Ubuntu doesn't have its own partitions, how did you install Ubuntu? Do you have a folder named `ubuntu` in your `C` drive?

Comment: it was a long time ago and i don't remember. All i do remember is: i tried wubi and it didn't work, file permissions or something, then i installed manually on c: i can't remember why

Answer (score 0):

I guess you still have the Ubuntu ISO or Ubuntu Live DVD. You can use Gparted partition editor which came with Ubuntu to delete the ubuntu partition and format it to NTFS.

Or On Windows open up Disk Management and just simply delete the Ubuntu partition. This will unallocate the space. Now create a logical partition from Disk Management.

If you installed using Wubi then run-> appwiz.cpl (add/remove programs) and there will be a uninstaller link. Use that to uninstall Ubuntu.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu partition

Comment: And there is no wubi

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can upgrade without problems, and because Ubuntu is installed within the Windows partition you don't need to repartition either.

You can delete Ubuntu before or after performing the upgrade to Windows 8 but in any case to remove Ubuntu you'll have to do this:

1. In your `C` drive you'll see a folder called `ubuntu`, everything related to your Ubuntu installation resides there, delete this folder to *uninstall* Ubuntu.
2. The next step is getting it out of the boot menu:

   2.1. Open an elevated command prompt, i.e. run `cmd` as an administrator.

   2.2. Execute `bcdedit /enum` and you'll see some information regarding the entries that are in your boot menu. Locate one similar to this one:

   [image: Ubuntu entry]

   2.3. Delete that entry from the BCD store with the following command:

   `bcdedit /delete {identifier}`

   Where `identifier` is the one in the Ubuntu entry you see in the output of the previous command. In this case for example it would be `{2eafb0df-2780-11e2-bfee-acc23b564ea2}`. After executing that you should see a text saying that the operation was successful.

Done, you'd have Ubuntu effectively. Note that you can execute those steps in reverse order too, you can first delete the entry from the BCD store and then remove the `ubuntu` directory.

*Just as a reminder, to perform an upgrade insert your Windows 8 DVD and run it from within Windows.*

Answer (score -1):

In your computer Ubuntu and windows 7 is installed in two different drives so while upgrading only the windows drive gets upgraded and Ubuntu files remain untouched. After up gradation you will find a folder on the windows drive named windows old in which all your windows 7  files will be there. The Ubuntu files remained untouched but you will have to re install since after up gradation you will not find the option to select the Ubuntu at the start up.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Wubi, it installs Ubuntu in C: and adds an entry in Add or Remove Programs. Just go to add or remove programs and uninstall Ubuntu from there. Then go ahead with your upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8 :)

Comment: I don't have installed with wubi

Comment: Then how can Windows and Ubuntu both reside in C: ?

Comment: @PratyushNalam - Its easy you just install your own bootloader.

Comment: I still don't understand..